# How can I change only one number from a certain line in a csv format file using linux comand?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
ID,Name,Salary,Email
23,John,3000,john@gmail.com
15,Mike,3200,mike@gmail.com
16,Tom,3500,tom@gmail.com
```

How can i change the salary of an employee using the ID as an identifier?

I tried

```
echo "Id: " 
read ID 
echo "New salary: " 
read s 
awk -F "," '{ if ($1 = $ID) $3 = $s } END{print $0}' employees.csv
```

Comment: Use `awk`. Set the field separator to `,`, match the employee number in `$1`. and assign the new salary to `$3`.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Condition: `$1 == emp_id`. Result `$3 = new_salary`

Comment: ok, so i will write awk -F "," to set the field separator and this will divide my csv in 4 field: $1, $2, $3 and for $4. But how can i change the 3rd field using the pattern from the first field?

Comment: I just showed you: `$3 = new_salary`, then print the line.  I'm not going to try to teach you how to program in awk here, you need to read a tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a begginer, a student, and i got this project for college. I tried to find something usefull but nothing.   I tried to run this code but the result is not what i expected.  Can you help me please?                                                                                           
echo "Id: "
read ID
echo "New salary: "
read s
awk -F "," '{ if ($1 = $ID) $3 = $s } END{print $0}' employees.csv

Comment: Also, just be careful about using `awk -F,` with CSV files, as it won't handle quoted fields with commas in them (which happens a lot in real-world data). May be better to use a CSV-aware tool like my [goawk](https://github.com/benhoyt/goawk) or the [frawk](https://github.com/ezrosent/frawk) tool for processing CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `==` for comparison, not `=`.

Shell variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. You should use the `-v`1 option to assign the shell variables to `awk` variables.

```
read -p "Id: " id
read -p "New salaray: " s
awk -F ',' -v id="$id" -v salary="$s" '$1 == id { $3 = salary; print }' employees.csv > new_employees.csv
```